# Can't update static cell in containerView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicontainerview

I have a containerView with a TableViewController and STATIC cells in it. For each item in my nested tableView I have a corresponding outlet and can easily use them to update UI in viewWillAppear and it works great, BUT nothing happens when I update them in tableView(_:didSelect/didDeselectRow). Cell selection is performed, model changes, all methods are called and outlets are properly set I can print all it while debugging but UI not get updated. setNeedsDisplay(), reloadData(), reloadRows(), reloadSections() useless in this case for both parent and container viewControllers.

Comment: Have you tried `layoutIfNeeded()` and please share some code if possible

Comment: yes, tried many ways and layoutIfNeeded() as well, but all I can do is to update outlets in nested ViewConroller lifecycle methods, it strange, because I can clearly see that new cell I pick draws it's background as selected and breakpointing in UI debugger I get my labels updated but not on my devise screen...

Comment: Does it run correctly on simulator?

Comment: No, I can see that it works in UI debugger, but neither for device nor for simulator. All happens on main thread

Answer (score 0):

I had some routing RIGHT AFTER all outlets update and that was the problem I guess. Suddenly after putting routing in completion block on main thread after I did all I want with outlets previous cell deselection and selection of newly picked one works as a charm.